# Following code displaying NAN and INF value on screen

Tags: php, mysql

Following code displaying INF and NAN value on screen when displaying values from mysql. I ran the query in mysql and I was able to get the desired values but on the web page while returning the values I get the above values.

```
function get_preelections_results_public(){
    global $mysqli;
    $return_data = "";
    $squery = "SELECT 'PreElection', (SELECT count(pu_name) from polling_unit) pu_count, (SELECT count( distinct pu_name) from pre_election_check_info) pu_reported_count,(SELECT count(distinct pu_name) from pre_election_check_info a WHERE inec_arrival_status='Yes' and security_arrival_status='Yes' and entry_date = (select max(entry_date) from pre_election_check_info b where a.pu_name=b.pu_name)) green_count,
    (SELECT count(distinct pu_name) from pre_election_check_info a WHERE inec_arrival_status ='Yes' and security_arrival_status ='No' and entry_date = 
    (select max(entry_date) from pre_election_check_info b where a.pu_name=b.pu_name)) amber_count_1, (SELECT count(distinct pu_name) from pre_election_check_info a WHERE inec_arrival_status ='No' and security_arrival_status ='Yes' and entry_date = (select max(entry_date) from pre_election_check_info b where a.pu_name=b.pu_name)) amber_count_2, (SELECT count(distinct pu_name) from pre_election_check_info a WHERE inec_arrival_status ='No' and security_arrival_status ='No' and entry_date = (select max(entry_date) from pre_election_check_info b where a.pu_name=b.pu_name)) red_count
    FROM pre_election_check_info LIMIT 1";
    $sresult = mysqli_query($mysqli, $squery) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($sresult);
    $total_pu_count = 0;
    $total_reported_pu_count = 0;
    $count_green_status = 0;
    $count_yes_no_status = 0;
    $count_no_yes_status = 0;
    $count_red_status = 0;
    $count_none_status = 0;
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sresult)){
        $total_pu_count = $row["pu_count"]; 
        $total_reported_pu_count = $row["pu_reported_count"];
        $count_green_status = $row["green_count"];
        $count_yes_no_status = $row["amber_count_1"];
        $count_no_yes_status = $row["amber_count_2"];
        $count_red_status = $row["red_count"];
        $count_none_status = $total_pu_count - $total_reported_pu_count;

        $green_status_percent = $count_green_status/$total_pu_count * 100;
        $amber_status_percent = ($count_yes_no_status+$count_no_yes_status)/$total_pu_count * 100;
        $red_status_percent = $count_red_status/$total_pu_count * 100;
        $none_status_percent = $count_none_status/$total_pu_count * 100;
        $red_status_percent+=$none_status_percent;

        $return_data .="Green,".$green_status_percent.";";
        $return_data .="Amber,".$amber_status_percent.";";
        $return_data .="Red,".$red_status_percent.";";
        //$return_data .="None,".$none_status_percent.";";
    }
    return rtrim($return_data,";");
}
```

What I am getting when results is being displayed;

**Green,INF;Amber,NAN;Red,NAN**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get `NAN` when you divide `0 / 0`, you get `INF` when you divide any other number by `0`.

So this result implies that `$row['total_pu_count']`, `$row['amber_count_1']`, `$row['amber_count_2']`, and `$row['red_count']` are all `0`.

You should check whether `$total_pu_count` is zero before doing any of the divisions.

```
if ($total_pu_count != 0) {
    $green_status_percent = $count_green_status/$total_pu_count * 100;
    $amber_status_percent = ($count_yes_no_status+$count_no_yes_status)/$total_pu_count * 100;
    $red_status_percent = $count_red_status/$total_pu_count * 100;
    $none_status_percent = $count_none_status/$total_pu_count * 100;
    $red_status_percent+=$none_status_percent;
}
```

Comment: please what can I do to resolve this? I am new to programming.

Comment: Make sure that `$total_pu_count` is more than 0 before doing all the calculations. I've updated the answer.